# What is the default Encoding Method used for Keyboard.SendKeys() in Coded UI

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, coded-ui-tests

I have a coded UI test project which I wrote it manually (not using wizard code), where I need to pass my user name & password as keys.

I don't want to store my password as hard coded. So I use Coded UI overloaded method SendKeys() method which accepts Password strings, and isEncoded bool value. But I'm not sure which encoded format it accepts, when I use visual studio wizard to generate it, it creates the encoded text automatically.

```
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard.SendKeys("mypassword", true);
```

Even in my other places in visual studio, i.e Connection string in Entity Framework it keeps the encoded credential. Anybody knows what is the encoding format, or how to encode without using visual studio?

Comment: SendKeys encoding is exactly same keybord language setting, but i dont recommanded you use SendKeys, because is has security risk

Comment: But another option i have is to set the text property of password control and set the value. For that i have to use my own encoding and decoding.     i.e.  txtPassword.Text = ""; Is there any other secured way to do  on UI automation?

Comment: you can pre-encrypt your password with `Playback.EncryptText()` and use the new value with the `Password` property.